# Unable to download a file which is containing special character in filename in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I am using file download tag, in that I am not able to download any file which is containing "+" operator, it says:

> "failed.No file".

Example: My Filename : My+Docx+Test.docx.

I surfed over internet, they advised me to encode and decode the URL but when I decode the URL I am getting the same error message.

Here is my code, kindly check it and give me our suggestion:

```
<a data-controlid="dwnld" id="dwnld_1fileDownload" class="downloadFile" style=" " href="http://localhost:50613/Templates/Test/My+Docx+Test.docx" download="/Templates/Test/My+Docx+Test.docx" target="_blank" tabindex="3">DownloadDOCX</a>
```

Comment: use %20 or change the file name to use underscores

Comment: I tried %20 also but while downloading , file path is not identified and i can't change the file name

Comment: Possibly your browser does not have access to your template folder

Comment: Can you load this from the location bar? `http://localhost:50613/Templates/Test/My+Docx+Test.docx`

Comment: Yes, I can load . and also If rename the filename to My_Docx_Test.docx, I can download but i cant change the filename

Comment: Try leaving the download attribute blank - it will take the filename from the href. the href MUST use %20 or underscores if you need, you can change them on click

Comment: Yeah okay I'll check and is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: There should not be an issue so no other way

Comment: I tried by leaving download attribute blank but still  facing the same issue

Comment: So the href is still `http://localhost:50613/Templates/Test/My+Docx+Test.docx` ? Then change it: `onclick="this.href=this.href.replace(/\+/g,'%20')"`